# MySQL CAST vs. CONVERT

Tags: mysql

Let's say that I have a VARCHAR (which contains numeric data) that I want to use for a simple computation (adding 10 to it).  According to the [MySQL documentation on CAST functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html), I could accomplish this with either a CAST or a CONVERT:

```
SELECT (CAST(field1 AS SIGNED)) + 10
FROM myTable;
```

or:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(field1,SIGNED)) + 10
FROM myTable;
```

What is the difference between CAST and CONVERT in this sense?  Are they both really accomplishing the same thing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, `CAST` and `CONVERT` do the same thing, except that `CONVERT` allows more options, such as changing character set with `USING`.

Comment: Is there a kind of performance difference o something like that... i meant there's must be a difference..

Comment: `cast` is part of the SQL standard, while `convert` is not

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what's the implication of that? Using standard SQL makes code portable, but it doesn't necessarily make it more efficient as far as I know. I'm still wondering about user7479's question.

Answer (score 2):

[Convert and cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html) docs.  Aside from the syntax I believe they can functionally be considered synonyms, even when trying to change character sets.